# Client Server communication over https using xml in android

Tags: android, ssl

This is the first time i am trying this. Can somebody pls share some bit of code which would help me doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Initial Attempt

hi,

I am trying to write code that will do client-server comm over https.

The code snippet(Mostly from different forums) for what i did is as under:

_FakeX509TrustManager.allowAllSSL();

The code for allowAllSSL() is

public static void allowAllSSL() { HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

```
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

    });

    SSLContext context = null;
    if (trustManagers == null) {
            trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new _FakeX509TrustManager() };
    }

    try {
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

}

Also in the main activity the code after the above is:

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(new URI(eText.getText().toString())); post.setEntity(new StringEntity("test"));

```
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            InputStream trustStoreStream = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytruststore);
            trustStore.load(trustStoreStream, "test1234".toCharArray());
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

            // Setup keystore
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            InputStream keyStoreStream = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mykeystore);
            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "test1234".toCharArray());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "test1234".toCharArray());

            SSLSocketFactory sslf = new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
            sslf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme ("https", sslf, 443));
            SingleClientConnManager cm = new
            SingleClientConnManager(post.getParams(), schemeRegistry);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, post.getParams());
            HttpResponse result = client.execute(post);
```

I have generated the JKS Keystore and Truststore files and kept it under /res/raw folder in my app.

The error which i get here is :

W/System.err( 358): java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found W/System.err( 358): at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:134) W/System.err( 358): at com.msi.getwebpage.GetWebPage$2.onClick(GetWebPage.java:93) W/System.err( 358): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) W/System.err( 358): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) W/System.err( 358): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) W/System.err( 358): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) W/System.err( 358): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) W/System.err( 358): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) W/System.err( 358): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) W/System.err( 358): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) W/System.err( 358): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) W/System.err( 358): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) W/System.err( 358): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any idea why am i getting this error?

Also if i am trying to change the KeyStore instance to BKS i am getting the error as:

W/System.err( 387): java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store. W/System.err( 387): at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyStore.engineLoad(JDKKeyStore.java:839) W/System.err( 387): at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:676) W/System.err( 387): at com.msi.getwebpage.GetWebPage$2.onClick(GetWebPage.java:96) W/System.err( 387): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) W/System.err( 387): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) W/System.err( 387): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) W/System.err( 387): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) W/System.err( 387): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) W/System.err( 387): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) W/System.err( 387): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) W/System.err( 387): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) W/System.err( 387): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) W/System.err( 387): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) W/System.err( 387): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is probably because i have kept the jks keystore and truststore files under /res/raw folder in my app.(just a guess).

Please let me know how can i generate a BKS keystore and truststore file.

Or is their any other way that i can try to make this code snippet working. Thanks!!

Comment: show that you already put some effort in it and ask more specifically. what experience do you have, what do you want to do?

Comment: Hi Markus, Above is the initial version i am trying.I don't have any experience as such in SSL communication.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Use keytool (from Java SDK) to export the certs from your jks keystore then import them to a new BKS keystore using bouncycastle security provider.